# I want to use Thymeleaf same as handlebars or freemarker

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I wanted to use Thymeleaf as simple string resolver like handlebars and did some code presuming it will work

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.15.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

code

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
data.put("name", "dickens");
data.put("age", "100");
TemplateEngine en = new TemplateEngine();
Context c = new Context(Locale.ENGLISH, data);
String p = en.process("Hello ${name} your age is ${age}", c);
System.out.println(p);
```

The output I am getting is

```
Hello ${name} your age is ${age}
```

I am expecting it will print `Hello dickens your age is 100`
I cannot to put `Hello [[${name}]] your age is [[${age}]]`
 that will be a major change everywhere, Is there any flag that I can enable string inline all places?

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Resolver:

```java
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.StringTemplateResolver;
    ...
    StringTemplateResolver resolver = new StringTemplateResolver();

    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.TEXT);
    ...
            en.setTemplateResolver(resolver);
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, but this did not help me

Comment: I have updated my answer to set the resolver's mode.  I hope this helps.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, but the string resolver did not work with the changes you have specified

Comment: Sorry it didn't help